# flask-blueprints - use decorator before function call with separated router and controller files

Tags: flask, flask-jwt-extended

I came accross this syntax:

```
users.route('/me', methods=["GET"])(get_user)
```

when instead of the usual definition after the route, I can just specify its name after the route, and define it in another file.
what about decorators? I'm using flask-jwt-extended for auth, can where is the right place to specify the decorator?
previous syntax, before separating the bluepring/routes from controller:

```
@users.route('/me', methods=["GET"])
@jwt_required()
def get_user():
<function code here>
```

Comment: hello, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't